# Incorrect overload/specialization due to wrong conversion

Tags: c++

After a bug in my own code, where (in my opinion) the wrong overload got selected by the compiler, I have been digging for an explanation but can not find an easy one. I did find [Herb Sutter's GOTW 49](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm) which deals with the issue of specialization. I also found a few questions on stackoverflow, but none could really explain the cause to me, nor provide me with good solutions.

I have a single class Foo, which can be constructed from a boolean. I found out (the hard way) that std::string can also be constructed from a bool (false).

I have three (template) methods with different arguments, as shown below. One method accepts "any" template argument, and two specializations, accepting a struct Foo and another accepts a string.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() : value( false ){ };
    Foo( bool v ) : value ( v ) { } 
    Foo( const bool& v ) : value( v ) { }

    bool value;
};

template< typename T >
void bar( const T& value )
{
    std::cerr << "template bar" <<  std::endl;
}

template< >
void bar< Foo >( const Foo& )
{
    std::cerr << "template bar with Foo" << std::endl;
}

template< typename T >
void bar( const std::string& )
{
    std::cerr << "template bar with string" << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    bar( false ); // Succeeds and calls 1st bar( const T& )
    bar< Foo >( false ); // Crashes, because 2nd bar( const std::string& )
                         // is called with false promoted to null pointer.

    return 0;
}
```

I have tested this with Visual Studio 2010 and with MinGW (gcc 4.7.0). GCC nicely gives a compile-warning, but msvc does not:

```
main.cpp:34:20: warning: converting 'false' to pointer type for argument 1 of 'std::basic_string< ... ' [-Wconversion-null]
```

Small update (in code): Even an explicit specialization with Foo does not work.\

Small update 2: The compiler does not complain about an "ambiguous overload".

Small update 3: Some people answer that the two constructors of Foo accepting a `bool`, "invalidate" the selection of Foo. I have tested similar versions with only a single conversion constructor. These don't work either.

Questions:

1. Why does the compiler try to call the string-argument version?
2. And why does the additon of `<Foo>` in the bar() call matter.
3. How can I prevent this from happening. E.g. could I force the compiler to select `bar( const Foo& )` when a bool is input?
4. Alternatively, could I enforce a compile-error when someone calls `bar< Foo >( false )`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the answers to the four questions:

1. Why does the compiler try to call the string-argument version? Your class `Foo` has two constructors taking a `bool` which are ambiguous and, thus, converting `bool` to `Foo` is not considered (if you want to detect if a temporary or an lvalue is passed in, you can overload in C++ using `bool&&` and `bool const&` as parameter types). `std::string` can be constructed from a `char const*` and `false` can be promoted to a null pointer constant. A null pointer constant is syntactically a valid `char const*` but it is an illegal value and passing it causes undefined behavior.
2. And why does the additon of  in the bar() call matter? When specifying the template argument you suppress template argument deduction and tells the compiler which argument to use. Specifying the template argument explicitly is the only way the overload of `bar()` taking a `std::string` can be chosen because `T` cannot be deduced for this template.
3. How can I prevent this from happening. E.g. could I force the compiler to select bar( const Foo& ) when a bool is input? The easiest way is to have the compiler deduce the template argument: the version of `bar()` s never chosen automatically by the compiler because the compiler can't deduce the template argument. Alternatively, if you want to specify the template argument explicitly and only `bool` is a problem, you can add an overload taking `bool` and make the deduced version and the `bool` version delegate to the same internal function.
4. Alternatively, could I enforce a compile-error when someone calls bar< Foo >( false )? This would be easy using C++ 2011 by deleting the overload (see below).

To create a compile-time error when using `bool` with an explicitly specified template argument, you could add this overload:

```
template <typename T> void bar(bool) = delete;
```

Deleting function is available in C++ 2011.

The main question seems to be: If `Foo` and `std::string` can both be converted from `bool`, why is the `std::string` conversion chosen if `bar<Foo>(bool)` is called and the following overloads are available?

```
template <typename T> void bar(T const&);
template <>           void bar<Foo>(Foo const&);
template <typename T> void bar(std::string const&);
```

First, overload resolution chooses the primary template, ignoring any specializations). Since `bar(std::string const&)` as a more specialized interface than the version deducing the template argument, this version is chosen. The specialization of the first template is ignored in this stage. To make the use of `Foo` applicable as well, you could add

```
template <typename T> void bar(Foo const&);
```

and calling `bar<Foo>(false)` would be an ambiguity between the `std::string` and the `Foo` version.

Comment: The first with all four answered. Thanks. About answer 1: Foo can be constructed from false as well... Why does it pick bar( string ) and not bar( Foo )?

Comment: You said in a comment to a since deleted answer that you started out with only the `const bool&` constructor. Thing is, I don't think the literal `false` is a `const bool&`. Can you try commenting that constructor out and see if it works?

Comment: Already tried all three combinations: both constructors, one with bool and one with const bool&. Does not work.

Comment: Also, +1 for deleting function!

Comment: @Andre: I forgot to comment on this. It can't be created from `bool` because the conversion is ambiguous. If you remove one of the constructors you should get an ambiguity because the conversion to `std::string` is as good as converting to `Foo`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess the compiler considers forming a null pointer to be a higher priority than invoking an explicit constructor, for some reason.

Comment: Ah, actually, no: the `std::string` version is chosen over the one deducing the template argument because it is more specialized. The specialized version taking a `Foo` looks equally specialized but actually isn't because first overload resolution chooses the primary template which matches best and then replaces this with a specialization, if applicable.

Comment: @Dietmar, OK, I think we are getting to a "complete" answer now. May I interpret your last comment as: false -> std::string is equally "valid/important" as false -> Foo, but when selecting a template method, it will prefer the non-specialized one which happens to have an exact match.

Comment: @Andre: I don't think it will "prefer the non-specialized". During overload resolution specializations of the primary template are not considered because the overload resolution chooses the primary template, not any specialization.

Comment: So, if I would have added a third "primary" template method, which accepts a bool, I would try to pick that one?

Comment: Yes, I think so: `template <typename> void bar(bool);`.

Answer (score 2):

The first example, `bar( false );` calls the `template<typename T> void bar( const T& value )` because that is an exact match with T = bool.

When you specify that T = Foo, neither of the overloads is an exact match anymore, so you get into the rather complicated rules about which implicit conversions are applied. Most C++ programmers don't fully understand these, so you're probably better off avoiding implicit conversions.

The easiest fix in this situation is to just add another overload for bool.

```
template<typename T>
void bar( bool )
{
    std::cerr << "bool" << std::endl;
}
```

then in that overload you can apply the conversion explicitly and call the version you want.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
bar< Foo >( false );
```

can match either of these two functions:

```
void bar<Foo>(const Foo&);
void bar<Foo>(const std::string&);
```

Now, if both UDTs have implicit conversion constructors from `bool`, which one should it choose? They both have the same priority, because they're both the same type of conversion.

At least ... presumably that's what is happening, although it really *shouldn't* choose a promotion+construction over a construction-only sequence.

Comment: If it matches both methods, why does the compiler not complain about "ambiguous overloads" (also added as a question)?

Comment: Dietmar's answer explains that having _two_ implicit constructors that could both match with equal priority removes the `Foo` construction path from consideration. You learn something every day!